# Bash: How to change a value in an array, that contains a variable, without changing the variable

Tags: bash, syntax

```
#!/bin/bash
c21=Apples
c31=Oranges
c41=Pears
movelist=(c21 c31 c41)
for movecheck in ${!movelist[@]} ; do
  eval "declare movecontents=$"${movelist[$movecheck]}""
  if [ "$movecontents" != "Oranges" ] ; then
  "${movelist[$movecheck]}"="" 
  fi
done
echo ${movelist[@]}
```

My goal here, is to have Line 9 set a/the value in the array to null / remove it from the array, hence the `=""`. However with the code as it is, because `${movelist[$movecheck]}` results in a variable, `c*1`, when declaring it as null, it spits out `c41= command not found`. I tried using eval & declare: `eval "declare "${movelist[$movecheck]}"=''"`, but with that, instead of removing the value from the array it changes the actual variable. So the outcome for the example code above should have the `movelist` array contain `(c21 c41)` at the end. Cheers.

Comment: This isn't a `sh` question -- `sh` doesn't support arrays at all.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: My bad, I just tagged it since I thought it would be related & never used SO before. Also cheers for shellcheck, looks very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Use `unset` to delete an array element:

```
$ a=(a b c d)
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="a" [1]="b" [2]="c" [3]="d")
$ unset a[2]
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="a" [1]="b" [3]="d")
```

So: `unset movelist[$movecheck]` is what you want.